# Firebase cloud message to ios and android devices

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I have an app with Android and iOS users, subscribed to Firebase Clould Messaging topics. Some users have access to send a message to these topics. I make an http request to send the message. The body looks like this:

```
{
    "to": "/topics/debug"
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Hi there",
      "title" : "Wow!",
      "sound": "default"

    },
     "priority": "high"
    "data": {
        "title": "Hi there",
        "body": "Wow",
   }
}
```

For android, in order to send data message, I need to use the "data" key, so that onMessageReceived is called.

However, ios needs the "notification" key, so that even if the app is killed the message will display. But, whenever I add the "notification" key, the android devices don't call onMessageReceived, and it isn't treated as a data message.

How can I solve this issue, to make one request which is work for both devices. If I do two requests (one with "notification" for ios, and one with "data" for android, the android devices get two notifications (one from onMessageReceived, and one from the system. Can I stop the android devices from showing the message if its sent with just the "notification" key?

I hope I explained the issue well, since this is how I understand the problem I have.

Thanks

Comment: I think you just forget the comma here `"priority": "high",` and "to": `"/topics/debug",` . I'm using both the notification and data in my android app. notification for message title and body only  and for the data is where you can put your other data like name, date, time and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this counts as an answer, but I realised an easy workaround, that I prescribed different topics to android and ios users, and set different code appropriate for each one, instead of having one topic for all users.